# Eclipse RCP Handler enablement based on selection

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm a bit stuck, because the resources are many and they don't clarfiy this issue for me.

Suppose I have a **command**, a **handler**, a **property tester**, and the result of these presented on the UI as a **coolbar item**.

Now, suppose I have several view extending the same base (e.g. `BaseView`). All of these views contain `ColumnViewer`s (e.g. `TableViewer`, `TreeViewer`) which act as **selection providers**.

- How does the `enableWhen` and `activeWhen` configurations know about the selection in those viewers? I can't imagine how the `selection` + `instanceOf` parameters work for `ISelection`(s).
- How is the selected object passed to the property tester? What instance do the `test` method receive (as the `receiver`)?
- I noticed with a breakpoint that there are many passes through the `setEnabled()` method of the handler. Is that normal behaviour? Would it be okay to override the `setEnabled`?

---

Code seems a little bit irrelevant to me here. But anyway, these snippets cover the questions:

```
// --------------------- 1 -----------------------

  <handler
        class="com.example.ggrec.handlers.SampleHandler"
        commandId="com.example.ggrec.commands.sampleCommand">
     <enabledWhen>
        <with
              variable="selection">
           <instanceof
                 value="org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection">
           </instanceof>
        </with>
     </enabledWhen>
  </handler>

// --------------------- 2 -----------------------

  <propertyTester
        class="com.example.ggrec.propertyTesters.SamplePropertyTester"
        id="com.example.ggrec.samplePropertyTester"
        namespace="com.example.ggrec.propertyTesters"
        properties="simpleTest"
        type="java.lang.Object">
  </propertyTester>

// --------------------- 3 -----------------------

/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class SamplePropertyTester extends PropertyTester
{
    @Override
    public boolean test(final Object receiver, final String property, final Object[] args, final Object expectedValue)
    {
        if (receiver instanceof ISelection) // What instance is this?
            System.out.println("RAINBOWS");

        return true;
    }
}

// --------------------- 4 -----------------------

/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public Object execute(final ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException 
    {
        final IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(), "", "meh");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabled(final Object evaluationContext)
    {
        super.setEnabled(evaluationContext); // Goes like crazy through here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `ViewPart` (and editor part) has a separate selection maintained by the selection service and set by your selection providers. The `enabledWhen` and `visibleWhen` use the selection for the currently active part obtained from the selection service for the part.

The property test calls are usually inside a `<with>` block in the enablement expression which establishes the object that is being tested. Something like:

```xml
<with
    variable="org.eclipse.ui.selection">
   <iterate
         operator="or">
      <adapt
            type="music.resources.data.IMusicFile">
            <or>
                <test property="music.isMusicOrPlaylist"/>
                <test property="music.isVideo"/>
            </or>
       </adapt>
    </iterate>
</with>
```

which is working with the current selection, requiring the selection to adapt to a particular type, and testing either of two properties.

Comment: Interesting choice of enablement parameters. How do `iterate` and `adapt` come in handy in this case?

Comment: If the tree / table allows multiple items to be selected `iterate` looks at each selection in turn, so with `or` specified just one of the selections has to match. `adapt` uses the `IAdapterFactory` interface to match the specified type with the selected object (so the UI object does not have to implement the interface directly).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Now, I do have one more question. Why are the property testers constantly called? If I have a few pieces of business logic in the `test` method, won't that slow down the whole system?

Comment: I don't see my testers being called all the time, just when something in a view changes (but there may be quite a few calls when this happens). Still they should not have to do anything too expensive or the UI may get unresponsive. The testers in my example are just looking at file content types.